# How to drag an Image from WhatsApp and then drop it to a Picture Box

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I'm trying to drag a picture from WhatsApp and then drop it to a PictureBox,
After trying the code below, I found that the program does not go to `Bitmap` or `FileDrop`, but goes directly to `UnicodeText`,
It contains a link preceded by a `blob`, but when I open the link in another browser, it does not find the image,

**`blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/6c6edf24-439c-430f-a678-4d5a54fff50c`**

This means that I will not be able to use the `WebClient` to download the image because it only exists on the same browser that created it.

**What prompted me to ask is that when I drag the same image from WhatsApp to another program such as `Obsidian` or `Paint 3D`, the image is easily dropped.**

```cs
        // After Enable drag and drop for the picture box => pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        private void PictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) || e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) || e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
        }

        private async void PictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            }
            else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = files[0];
                }
            }
            else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))
            {
                var url = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText);

                if (url.StartsWith("blob:"))
                {
                        try
                        {
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                            var data = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
                            {
                                var bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
                                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = url;
                }
            }
        }
```

I also tried:

```cs
if (Clipboard. ContainsImage())
     {
         pictureBox1. Image = Clipboard. GetImage();
     }
```

Comment: The `blob:` protocol is actually a memory allocation, where the URI represents the source address reference and the GUID the identifier of the data bytes. The data is relatively complicated to retrieve: the `FileGroupDescriptorW` data format returns a MemoryStream; the first 4 bytes represent the number of [FILEDESCRIPTORW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-filedescriptorw) structures that follow right after. With that, you invoke a method of the internal (`innerData` Field) `IComDataObject`, `GetDataFromHGLOBLAL()` (<- not misspelled :)

Comment: You have another problem, now: WhatsUp transfers files using the `webp` format (quite possible anyway), which is not compatible with any System.Drawing format, so you need an external library for that. You can recognize the webp format from its signature: `82 73 70 70` (`R I F F`), then an int (file size), then `87 69 66 80` (`W E B P`). The `FILEDESCRIPTORW`'s `cFileName` member should represent the file name + its extension, though

Comment: Can you show me that with an example?, I will be very thankful.